# realizar divisiones exactas e inexactas en javaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

¡Hola!

¿Cómo puedo hacer una condición para que me muestre  una división entera sin decimal y si la división es inexacta muestre el decimal?

```js
if (P % Q === 0) {
  R1 = (P / Q).toFixed()
} else {
  R1 = (P / Q).toFixed(1)
}
```

Comment: si usas el operador `%` te da el resto de una división. osea `5 % 2` te devuelve 1. De todas maneras, debes poner algo de codigo de lo que estas haciendo y lo que has intentado

Answer (score 1):

Tal como tienes tu código debería funcionar, lo único es, que si el resultado es un entero, no necesitas usar `toFixed()`

```js
let P = 10;
let Q = 2;

if (P % Q === 0) {
  R1 = (P / Q)
} else {
  R1 = (P / Q).toFixed(1)
}

console.log(R1);
```

```js
let P = 10;
let Q = 3;

if (P % Q === 0) {
  R1 = (P / Q)
} else {
  R1 = (P / Q).toFixed(1)
}

console.log(R1);
```